# What should I use for push notification(No Google Cloud Message)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want a push notification, when there is data in server change,delete or added etc The notification is associated with the user. And the Google Cloud Messaging notification is associated for the application running in device. Also there is a lot of over head for developers, when developer are creating the system using google cloud message. Therefore I decide not to use Google Cloud Message.

I know is using XMPP or WebSocket can fulfill my requirement but it is battery inefficient. My question is there a better approach to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "lot of over head" you are referring to. We cannot help you avoid this "lot of over head", in GCM or alternatives, if we do not know what "lot of over head" means to you.

Comment: I mean register id is associated application and I was searching in google, I find my complicate steps to handle registeration id

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946586/gcm-with-login-system Please take a look. Thank you, For your time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786680/gcm-send-notifications-only-for-the-current-user-logged-in-application

Comment: My question can be little related to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176797/in-app-notification-triggered-from-a-background-service-android

Answer (score 0):

You can send the GCM registration Id in the login request to the server and remove it once the user logs out. This way you can send a GCM message to a particular user.

If you want to use a GCM alternative you can try [Pushy.me](http://pushy.me), its also a very good service that uses MQTT protocol and have less headaches as compared to GCM.

Comment: I was talking about this overhead in your first part of answer. @Ahmed :) I will search for Push.me .. Thank you

Comment: Cool, try it out. I believe sending registration ID on login and clearing on logout is not a very big overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific needs, using an alarm and intent service to poll your server every so often - say 24 hours - can work. Then create a local notification if needed. This way no third parties are needed, but you won't have real time notifications.